# Generar solo un numero aleatorio, Ayuda PorFavor

Tags: java

Hola quiero generar solo un numero aleatorio dentro de un while, osea digamos que vegeta esta haciendo un recorrido con velocidad 45 y su meta es de 500, quiero que caiga en un recorrido aleatorio solo uno que aumente su velocidad tambien aleatoriamente

```js
package edu.cibertec.hilos;

import java.util.Random;

import edu.cibertec.carrera.CarreraMain;

/**
 * Esta clase permite agregar el comportamiento de hilos a objetos a través de interfaz Runnable.
 * @author Marcelo Tataje
 *
 */
public class VegetaRunnable implements Runnable {

 /**
  * Velocidad asignada al hilo.
  */
 final int VELOCIDAD = 45;
 
 /**
  * Tiempo de descanso para el hilo.
  */
 final int DESCANSO_MS = 1000;
 
 /**
  * La distancia recorrida que se irá incrementando.
  */
 private int distanciaRecorrida = 0;
 
 public int hola;
 
 @Override
 public void run() {
  System.err.println("Vegeta ha iniciado la carrera");
  while (distanciaRecorrida < CarreraMain.DISTANCIA_TOTAL) {
   int hola =distanciaRecorrida += VELOCIDAD;
   System.err.println(String.format("Vegeta ha avanzado: %d en la carrera", hola));
   try {
    Thread.sleep(DESCANSO_MS);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Ocurre cuando se intenta acceder a un hilo que no se encuentra en estado de ejecución 
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  Random r = new Random(); 
  int  resultado = (int) (r.nextFloat() * (500 - hola) + hola);
  System.err.println(String.format("resulktado", resultado));
  System.err.println("->Vegeta ha terminado la carrera");
 }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! dos cosas, tu codigo ya obtiene un numero aleatorio, donde estas teniendo el problema? y por favor, utilizar nombres de variables con sentido. La variable hola no dice nada sobre lo que contiene

Answer (score 0):

¿Has intentado declarar la variable `resultado` global? Puedes incializarla en -1 y despúes en un if compruebas el valor, si es menor a 0 obtienes un numero aleatorio y lo guardas en `resultado`, de otra forma no haces nada.

```
package edu.cibertec.hilos;

import java.util.Random;

import edu.cibertec.carrera.CarreraMain;

/**
 * Esta clase permite agregar el comportamiento de hilos a objetos a través de interfaz Runnable.
 * @author Marcelo Tataje
 *
 */
public class VegetaRunnable implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Velocidad asignada al hilo.
     */
    final int VELOCIDAD = 45;

    /**
     * Tiempo de descanso para el hilo.
     */
    final int DESCANSO_MS = 1000;

    /**
     * La distancia recorrida que se irá incrementando.
     */
    private int distanciaRecorrida = 0;

    public int hola;

    private int resultado = -1; // variable global

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.err.println("Vegeta ha iniciado la carrera");
        while (distanciaRecorrida < CarreraMain.DISTANCIA_TOTAL) {
            int hola =distanciaRecorrida += VELOCIDAD;
            System.err.println(String.format("Vegeta ha avanzado: %d en la carrera", hola));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(DESCANSO_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ocurre cuando se intenta acceder a un hilo que no se encuentra en estado de ejecución 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(resultado < 0) { // comprobamos
            Random r = new Random(); 
            resultado = (int) (r.nextFloat() * (500 - hola) + hola);
        }
        System.err.println(String.format("resulktado", resultado));
        System.err.println("->Vegeta ha terminado la carrera");
    }

}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola gracias, como vegeta va en 45 en 45 hasta llegar al 500 como hago que me genere un numero aleatorio que sea en 45 en 45 hasta el 500?

Comment: A ver, explicate mejor. La verdad no entiendo a lo que te refieres. Quizás quieres decir que comience a generar números al azar de 45 hasta 500?